# Python: Storing output in Variable

Tags: python, bash, python-3.x, shell

Im new to Python and i wonder how to store an input or output in a Variable.

In Shell-Script i can use this to store the output of the Command in a Variable

```
Variable_name=$(Command)
```

Then i can use it like this for example:

```
start_num=$(input start number) 
increment_num=$(input increment number) 

i=$start_num;
while [[ i -le $increment_num ]] ;
  do
```

Here is my Python code that of course doesn't work:

```
first = int(input("Enter the starting number: "))
second = int(input("Increment it by: "))

def start(first):
        return(first)

def increment(second):
        return(second)

count = start
while count != 100:
        count += increment
        print(count)
```

I got here another exercise i wrote:

```
first = int(input("Enter first number: "))
second = int(input("Enter second number: "))


def adding(first, second):
        return(first + second)

result = adding(first, second)

print(result)

def plustest(result):
        return(result + 100)

result2 = plustest(result + 100)
print(result2)
```

What i dont like is that i have to write "adding(first, second):" twice instead of getting it straight from the def.

```
def adding(first, second):
        return(first + second)

result = adding(first, second)
print(result)
```

like

```
result="def adding(first, second):
        return(first + second)"
print($result)
```

or

```
result=$(def adding(first, second):
        return(first + second))
print($result)
```

I dont want to reinvent Python but i wonder how to achieve what i could easily do in Shell-Script in python. Also if anyone would have a guess what language would come close to a mix between Shell-Script and Python. Im used to Shell-Script and i like using pipe, grep, seg, paste etc but im missing the advantages of a real programming language. Hope it makes sense.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The code below works to take inputs and perform simple arithmetic on them.

```
first = int(input("Enter first number: "))
```

Input 1

```
second = int(input("Enter second number: "))
```

Input 2

```
result = first + second

print result

>>> 3

print result + 1

>>> 4
```

Comment: That is very good if i want to store the imput1 and imput2 in result. My issue is that i have Input1 and Imput2 and i process it to result and then i want to take result and process it some more or print it. So i cant just print first and second because thats pre processing it. I could write it for each specific case but i want to store output in X and reuse X afterwards.

Comment: When you do `result = first + second`, the value is stored in `result` variable. You can use this variable wherever you want to, and change it, for example, `result = result + 1`.

Comment: Is it possible to store the output of an operation into "result" by targeting the operations output instead of the parameters? Kind of like this:                     result = def adding(first, second):
            return(first + second)                                                                                    print(result)

Comment: That would be a very round about way of performing the arithmetic. The function you have described in the comment above is what is performed in my answer.